# What is TTP hunting?

Tags: detection, terminology

What is "TTP hunting" in terms of network security research?

I came across this term, but do not know what this is . Tried to google it, but TTP seem to stand for many different things, but none of them seemed related to network security or malwares.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this](https://sqrrl.com/solutions/cyber-threat-hunting/) TTP refers to the **T**actics, **T**echniques and **P**rocedures of cyber threats.

Edit:

> Traditional security measures like firewalls, IDS, endpoint protection, and SIEMs are only part of the network security puzzle. Cyber Threat Hunting refers to proactively and iteratively searching through networks or datasets to detect and respond to threats that evade traditional rule- or signature-based security solutions. It includes using both manual and machine-assisted techniques, and **aims to find the Tactics, Techniques and Procedures (TTPs) of advanced adversaries**.